# Need XML Response in descending order and total count

Tags: php, xml

```
 <?php
            $xml = simplexml_load_string( $response->ApiCallDeatilDataFeedResult );

            foreach ( $xml->call_data as $data )
            {
            ?>
            <tr>

                <td  class="sss"><?php 

                echo $data->call_time;?></td>
                <td  class="sss"><?php 

                $init = $data->call_duration;
$hours = floor($init / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($init / 60) % 60);
$seconds = $init % 60;

echo "$minutes Min : $seconds Sec";
?></td>
                <td  class="sss"><?php echo $data->call_status;?></td>
                <td  class="sss"><?php echo $data->caller_number;?></td>
                <td  class="sss"><?php echo $data->caller_name;?></td>

                <td  class="sss"><?php echo $data->caller_city;?></td>
                <td  class="sss"><?php echo $data->caller_state;?></td>
                <td  class="sss"><?php echo $data->caller_zip;?></td>

            </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
```

While request the xml i reciveing xml response which is  give result in ascending order.  I need XML response in descending order and need no of rows in total.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of [@Yogesh Suthar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679187/yogesh-suthar) is correct (despite calling count on $xml directly instead of $xml->call_data) , but I think the indices are wrong since an array index starts from zero and ends at length-1.

EDIT:
As [@hakra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakra) stated in the comments, call_data is not an array, but an iterable SimpleXMLElement.
But for the sake of argument, let us say that it is. So, I think it should be:

```
for($i = count($xml->call_data) - 1 ;$i >= 0 ; $i--)
```

Or, if you want to avoid the trouble of using indices, try using [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) if call_data is indeed an array

```
foreach ( array_reverse($xml->call_data) as $data )
```

Comment: does $xml->call_data return an object? I ask because I could not find it in the [documentation of SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php), which simplexml_load_string returns.

Comment: Yes, it always returns an object (another SimpleXMLElement one). `count` does work (it implements the `countable` interface), but before getting an array out of it, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12639079/367456

Comment: Can you provide a link to any documentation where call_data is defined? (just for reference). All I can find in the documentation is that $xmldoc itself is iterable, but I could not find any reference to  the call_data attribute.

Comment: Those attributes are created dynamically, e.g. the XML element `<root><element/></root>` will become `$xml->element;`. Each one again is a `SimpleXMLElement`, compare: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have never used SimpleXMLElement myself, but I used DOMDocument in combination with DOMXPath queries which returns a DOMNodeList and not a single element.

Comment: DomDocument is more powerful and has a better interface I'd say. SimpleXML is that shady and you run into these issues then :) You can use both at once btw. and convert from and to. Behind it, the same library is working. [`simplexml_import_dom`](http://php.net/simplexml_import_dom) is one of the conversion functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [krsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) for the sorting. And yeah use count() to count the array.

Comment: which array are you talking about? when I see that right, there is no array in question.

Comment: The code says: `foreach ( $xml->call_data as $data )`. Good luck using  foreach on other than arrays and objects. And you can cast either of those as arrays by simpkly putting (array) in front of it. This can then be sorted using krsort.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm concerned about: In question it is a simplexml object, you assume it would have been an array. I just pointed that out, you then took the cast-escape-lane. This is probably news to you then: 1.) foreach works on iterators which are special objects controlling the iteration 2.) you can not cast those iteration values via `(array)` 3.) the object in question is such an iterator (simplexml element) which leads to finally that this is not working what you suggest. Apart from that, the keys here are the xml elements names, krsort is totally useless.

Answer (score 1):

Simplexml is offering an iterator for the `foreach`, if you want to reverse it, you could convert it to an array, reverse the array and then `foreach` over the array:

```
$datas = $xml->call_data;
$datas = iterator_to_array($datas, 0);
$datas = array_reverse($datas);

foreach($datas as $data)
{
    ...
}

$count = count($datas);
```

Comment: He does not ask for a reverse order, but a descending order. There's a difference.

Comment: @EsbenTind: Read the question: *"While request the xml i reciveing xml response which is give result in ascending order."* Decend is reverse of Ascend. In this case there is no difference.

Comment: strange that this answer got downvoted, since it should work theoretically

Comment: Oh, that happens. Another user was not confident I suppose, but I'd say less with the answer itself ;)

Answer (score 0):

use `count` for number of rows and use `for` loop in reverse for descending order like this example

```
for($i = count($xml) ;$i >0 ; $i--)
{
   // your code
}
```

Comment: You loop some numbers, but how to loop the actual simplexml objects?